# Query Feature License total count

Tags: api, licenses

We can query the feature license count being used as below:

```sql
SELECT count() 
FROM User 
WHERE UserPermissionsMarketingUser = true AND isActive = true
```

Is there any way I can query the total feature license count that is being displayed under company information in UI?

Comment: No, that is giving information about user license. I need for feature license.

Comment: Have you looked at this post:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321017/can-we-query-on-feature-licenses-in-apex-to-get-the-remaining-licenses

Comment: @DavidCheng thanks but the answer in the mentioned post is for User license, not for feature license.